# Meromorphic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(s) > 0$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

I am trying to obtain the meromorphic continuation of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re(s) > 0$. Using the Abel's summation formula I've obtained that
$$
\sum_{n \leq x}\frac{1}{n^s}=\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} + s\int_1^x \frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{t^{s+1}}dt.
$$
Letting $x \longrightarrow \infty$ we have
$$
\zeta(s)= \frac{s}{s-1} - s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}dt
$$
for all $s$ with $Re(s) > 1$.

How can I continue after this point?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that
$$s \mapsto \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}dt$$
is a holomorphic function on $\{\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0 \}$ follows from the dominated convergence theorem: it tells you that you may interchange the order of differentiation and integration.